# Kongregate statistics API only works in preview mode

Tags: javascript, kongregate

I've made a game with HTML5 and Javascript, and uploaded it to Kongregate. The game uses Kongregate statistics API to report the player's reached level and high score.

I have uploaded the game, and tested it in preview mode. Everything worked correctly, and after ending the game, the player could see his score in the high score table.

This is what appears in the web developer console.

```
[Konduit] Kongregate Packet[kong_web] stat.submit: {"stats":{"121151":1},"success":true} [Game] StatServices.submit ( maxlevel, 1 ) game.html
[Konduit] [Game->Service]: stat.submit: {"req.id":1,"stats":[{"value":1,"name":"maxlevel"}]} 
Object { flushlow: Array[1] } 
Object { statList: 1 } 
[Konduit] Kongregate Packet[kong_web] stat.submit: {"stats":{"121151":1},"success":true} 
[Konduit] [maxlevel-ServerUpdate]: submitted=1 
[Konduit] [Service->Game]: stat.submit: {"stats":{"121151":1},"success":true}
```

However, after I hit the publish button, it suddenly broke. The call was still getting pushed, but no feedback came back.

The line indicating connection success has appeared.

```
[Service->Game]: hello: {"success":true}
```

However, the one indicating stat submission success hasn't.

```
[Game] StatServices.submit ( maxlevel, 1 ) game.html
[Konduit] [Game->Service]: stat.submit: {"stats":[{"value":1,"name":"maxlevel"}],"req.id":1}
```

EDIT: Now it seems to be working properly, and I didn't even change anything.